# Azure function to send push notifications (Notification Hub + NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-notificationhub

I'm working on an Azure function that will use the Azure notification hub module to send push notifications. The official documentation for the notification hub contains only samples using .Net. I could not find anywhere the official documentation for the Notification Hub NodeJs library. Can anyone who had the chance to work on something similar and can shed some light on the path to follow? That would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official provides a sample document about nodejs using notificationhub.

**[1. Sending push notifications with Azure Notification Hubs and Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-nodejs-push-notification-tutorial)**

**[2. Azure Notification Hubs modules for JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/notification-hubs?view=azure-node-latest)**

You also can read this blogs about [Push Notifications Tutorial](https://www.intertech.com/push-notifications-tutorial-node-js-and-azure-setup/), and you can read related links, hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had the same references and still was not successful (the sample provided by MS did not work for me). HOWEVER, and this is for anyone that comes across the same issue, the article provided here (https://www.intertech.com/push-notifications-tutorial-node-js-and-azure-setup/) (your third link) did specifically mention using the DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature endpoint in the notification hub instead of the DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature, and that was the root cause for not working for me.